# Location of hue.ini to set share_jobs in CDH 4.7

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, hue, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I'm attempting to set the share_jobs setting described [HERE](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hue_configuration.html?scroll=topic_15_6_7_unique_1) to `false`.

The documentation [HERE](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_hue_configuration.html) says to visit `http://myserver:port/dump_config` to find the location of the HUE config.  For me it gives `/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/73-hue-HUE_SERVER/`.

As you may guess from it being in `/var/run/` the directory is recreated every time on boot so changes to the `hue.ini` are not saved and do not seem to affect the config listed at `http://myserver:port/dump_config`.

I ran `find / -name hue.ini` to see if there was another `hue.ini` to change.  It returned:

```
/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/73-hue-HUE_SERVER/hue.ini 
/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/69-hue-BEESWAX_SERVER/hue.ini
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/share/hue/desktop/conf/hue.ini
/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-4.7.0-1.cdh4.7.0.p0.40/etc/hue/hue.ini
```

I've changed the config in each of these files to no avail.  Where exactly is the `hue.ini` that I need to change?

I've also been looking around the Cloudera Manager for the `jobbrowser` section in the configuration but I have not been able to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hue.ini file inside the server configuration directory (/var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/73-hue-HUE_SERVER/) should be modified that too not directly, should use CM instead. Location of the configuration directory will be changed during restart or applying new configurations.

Usually important service configurations will be listed in the cloudera manager configuration section. Configuration properties which are unimportant or new may not be listed, in that case these properties are supplied in the safety_val sections.

Go to CM Hue service configuration section search for **hue_safety_valve_server.ini**, then add the following

```
[jobbrowser]
share_jobs=false
```

Save and restart. Now if you go and check the /var/run/cloudera-scm-agent/process/XXX-hue-HUE_SERVER/hue.ini file you can see the change. What ever contents you  are giving in safety_val will get appended to hue.ini file.

Comment: Perfect.  Do you know where this is mentioned in the documentation?

Comment: Don't know the exact location, But you should find the safety_valve section somewhere in Cloudera documentation. This is same for all cloudera managed hadoop services.